# HTML titles don't render correctly in Chrome on OS X

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User summary page’s <title> missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131025/user-summary-pages-title-missing)

When I navigate to a StackOverflow profile using Chrome v24.0.1312.52, the HTML title renders correctly in the containing tab momentarily, but then it switches to the current URL of the profile, like so:

[image]

This is only reproducible on the OS X version of Chrome.

I've hacked around a bit in the JS console to get a gist of what's going on. If it helps anyone, I've found that `document.title` is an empty string. This apparently tells Chrome to render the URL of the page as its title.

Comment: Is this specific to Stack Overflow only?

Comment: @BoltClock Yes.

Comment: It happens only for user profiles, though. For questions, the title is correctly shown.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Correct.

Comment: All browsers behave the same with respect to an empty title by the way. Just something you don't need to know.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on Windows with that same Chrome build number.

Comment: Long time bug and it happens to me on all sites.